# How do I use <select> in inline js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet-draw

In my leaflet map I want the user to input some information about a place. This currently looks like this:

```
var formPopup= L.popup();
      var content = '<span><b>Name</b></span><br/><input id="shapeName" type="text"/><br/><br/>' +
                    '<select id="shapeType" option value="House" option value="Rock"></select><br/><br/>'+
                    '<input type="button" id="okBtn" value="Save" onclick="saveIdIW()"/>';
```

Now, I know the way I try to use `option` and `value` here is quite wrong. Unfortunately, my google-fu failed me in finding how to do it correctly.

Comment: `<option>` is a tag, not an attribute

Comment: I suggest reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrong in `option` tag syntax:

```
 var content = '<span><b>Name</b></span><br/><input id="shapeName" type="text"/><br/><br/>' +
                '<select id="shapeType"><option value="House">House</option><option value="Rock">Rock</option></select><br/><br/>'+
                '<input type="button" id="okBtn" value="Save" onclick="saveIdIW()"/>';
```

Comment: Thank you, mate! Exactly what I needed. Regular <select> is simple, but I was really confused how to nest that here. Again, thanks!